# 2012 Community Moderator Town Hall Chat

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary. I will be working with candidates to schedule a time appropriate for them.

***The Town Hall Chat will take place on Thursday, August 2nd, at 1:00:00Z UTC / This is Wednesday, August 1st at 9pm EDT***

**[view in other timezones](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=8&day=2&year=2012&hour=1&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)**

**[register here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/300/elu-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule)**

**[join the room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/300/elu-town-hall-chat)**

Here are the details so far:

- I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the primary phase.  This means that I am looking at July 30th - August 2nd. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=english.stackexchange.com).  I will update this post with a direct link to the chat room once the event is scheduled.
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidates regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, a digest of the event will be permanently linked here.

Comment: Good grief. Couldn't really have been a worse time for Europeans.

Comment: @Andrew See answer below. Wish I could give a better solution but this is the most I can manage for now.

Comment: what is registering for?

Comment: @Mitch Registration mostly just gives a good way to see who all will be there. There's no requirement to register in order to attend. Think of it just as a means to confirm, "Yes, I'll totally be there".

Comment: jwpat7's question to TecBrat about which questions he would close/delete/reopen and reasons is excellent and should be posed to all (except it's not good for chat, more like homework).

Comment: For those who never caught jwpat7's question before it was self-deleted: "Please edit your post and add: 3 examples of closed questions you wouldn't have closed; some examples of not-closed questions you would close; and closed questions you'd delete."

Comment: Does anyone know if we can we continue to edit our nomination text after the deadline? Also, I will not be around for the town hall chat, sorry. (It's not Grace Note's fault; I hadn't submitted my nomination yet when she set the time and date.)

Comment: @Martha Yes, you can edit it after primaries start. And sorry about the scheduling - remember though, that if you can't directly attend the event, you can still answer any questions that were asked (and as noted below, feel free to provide any questions for people to answer at the time).

Comment: @GraceNote: so it is recommended that at the very least that the nominees be present for the chat (if schedules permit) or at least inform people (like Martha has done) that they won't be available at that time?

Comment: @AndrewLeach, as a candidate in the recent Mi Yodeya election (town hall ended 1AM my time), I feel your pain.  FWIW, my experience during that chat was that the questions were coming quickly enough that all I could do was read and respond, mostly not reading what other candidates were saying (did that the next morning).  Thus, the candidate who couldn't attend and answered the next morning did not seem disadvantaged to me, and those later additions were included in the digest.  With even more candidates here I suspect that'll be even more pronounced and you won't lose out by answering later.

Comment: @Mitch It's generally easier to have more nominees present but I'm not going to force people to stay up when it's well past their bedtimes. Whether or not they mention it in advance, they're free to answer at any later time. The digest we make usually is delayed in posting until we get responses from those who couldn't attend (and there aren't any individuals who personally informed me that they'd be in, say, France until after the elections).

Answer (score 1):

As the timing of the event, while (thus far) the best for candidates, may not be optimal for attendees (England does in fact consistitute a good portion of English speakers), I'm setting up a bit of a "question preset" here. Leave a comment on this answer with your question and I will ask it on your behalf in the Town Hall Chat.

Some inspiration to look at would be the recent Town Halls for [Super User](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/236/2012/7/18) and [Mi Yodeya](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4146/2012/7/19) - I've specifically picked these two as they have a large amount of site-specific inquiries in both. There are a lot of "generic" questions that are asked in almost every Town Hall - these are unnecessary to comment here as I'll probably ask them anyway (if someone else who shows up doesn't already intend to) - focus instead on your own questions that you think might *not* get asked.